# Adding tooltip with a element's X, Y Coordinates

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can i add a tooltip with an element's x,y co-ordinates.   Is it possible to add bootstrap tooltip ? (I knew that bootstrap uses css selectors to add tooltips, just a small doubt)

Any other suggestions ???

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is offering some great solutions to make custom tooltips including positioning and custom design and everything crossbrowser friendly. Have a look at [THIS](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tooltip/index.html) or if you want other solutions [THIS](http://speckyboy.com/2009/09/16/25-useful-jquery-tooltip-plugins-and-tutorials/).